# positioned items causing problems when zooming in or zooming out

Tags: css, zooming

I noticed that some of the absolute positioned images are not aligning with the content when the zoom level of the site page changes, how to fix that, please give css fix for that. please refer to the screenshot of images on zoom levels on below to understand the problem on detail.

[image with 100% zoom](http://img291.imageshack.us/i/snap20110308161327001.jpg/)

[Image when zoomed in](http://img841.imageshack.us/i/snap20110308161450003.jpg/)

Comment: the problem occurs when we zoomed  out the  web page also.

Comment: Which browsers are you testing in? You haven't given us the CSS you're using - how can we tell you how to fix it? If possible, create a test case using [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/).

Comment: how to post codes on there, whats the format, iam new on there, so please help me..

Comment: The site html and css codes are uploaded to mediafire and you can view it for further informations , the link is http://www.mediafire.com/?m68ut9kh7mhv6